# How to restore activity state in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

How do I get out of an activity and restore it in exactly what it have in its previous state?
In that activity, I have spinner. If i select 2nd item from drop-down, i get out from that activity and again go back, the activity is getting reloading. But i want to restore what exactly the activity have previously?

```
spinner.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    dealerCd_fromDD = dealerInsp.getMap2().get(
                            dealerInsp.getLoadseqArray()[arg2]);
                    GlobalVehicle.setVehList(loadVehicles(dealerCd_fromDD));
                    loadHosts(GlobalVehicle.getVehList());
                    dealerDetails(dealerCd_fromDD, GlobalVehicle.getDealerObject());
                    loadDefaults(arg2);
                    pos=arg2;
                    deliveryInspDb.delete("damages");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Please any one can help me on this..

I tried to call finish(), but i am coming to that activity from 3 different activities. so in that situation its not working..

Comment: you only want spinner selcted data or whole data ?

Comment: i don't know what is your snario but when i worked something like this so i made a signlton class and on **new Intent** and **on back key pressed** i saved data in siglton, and when i reached again to activity i loaded it from singlton class where i saved before, you can use statics

Comment: Could you please post some example code of that..?

Answer (score 0):

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implement-swiping-between-tabs-with-viewpager-in-action-bar-using-sherlock-library/                                                                                     Try using Fragment. You can follow up the link.

Comment: In our requirement, we are extending "Activity"

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) on the `onStop()` or `onPause()` and retrieve it `onRestart()` event of your activity.

```
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();                      
            editor.putInt("Selected", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor.commit();
        }
     ....

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();          
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        spinner.setSelection(settings.getInt("Selected", 0));           
    }
```

You can also retrieve it `onCreate()`, if you want that your data should be restored even if your activity was killed

Update: If you are coming from different activities, you can try `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, this will bring your activity to front if it was not killed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onSaveInstanceState` for saving the activity state and `onRestoreInstanceState` FOR RETREIVING THE ACTIVITY STATE..
Check out this link, it will probably solve the issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/1626878